# Why should I be a freelancer

Tags: project-management

I would like to know why people would prefer to freelance than to work as an employee.
I hope to get various answers. I don't think there would be a definitive answer to this question.
PS:
Again not sure which tag to use.

Comment: Hello, johan! Here on Stack Exchange, we like questions that are answerable and whose answers aren't opinion-based. While we are lenient with this at times, asking "why should I freelance" is quite subjective, so I'd [edit] your question into something a little more objective.

Answer (score 1):

There are various reasons. As a Freelancer what I think is:

1. A Freelancer is free to work. He is not bound for certain  working hours.
2. He is free to accept or reject any work.
3. He is free to choose his rates. (I think that usually freelancers charge less than any other employee)
4. A freelancer can do various jobs at a time from his home or any other location. He is not bound to sit and work in office.
5. A Freelancer is not bound to have a physical work location. He can take work just via telling his country name. (No need to disclose his complete address)

Comment: I disagree that freelancers usually charge less than their employee counterparts. Freelancers should be charging more because it is necessary to take into account office expenses, etc. that employees don't have.